# How to assign boost's big_intN_buf_t to vector<uint8_t>?

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

I have a C++ vector of `uint8_t`s and I'm using boost to convert some int data to big-endian (on a little-endian architecture):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
boost::endian::big_int16_buf_t test;

test = 4096;
```

I'd like to achive to put the value of test into the buffer. Without changing endianness, the buffer would contain:

```
16,0
```

But I expect this boost type to do the conversion, so I'd like to have this in the buffer:

```
0,16
```

There is a `value_` attribute of these boost types, but those are private and I think they had some good reasons for this.

So, what is the best way to put this boost endian value to the buffer?

Comment: The best way is simple, elementary math. The same math which you use to take a plain `int`, containing the same value 4096, and having nothing to do with boost; and then break it down into the same result: `0, 16`. Do you know how to do that? Then do the same thing with Boost. Perusing Boost's documentation, this class's `value()` returns the numerical value, 4096 in this case, and you're off to the races. Mission accomplished!

Comment: I'm looking for some more 'modern' than this: `buffer.push_back((uint8_t)(test&0xff)); buffer.push_back((uint8_t)((test>>8)&0xff));`. Although I know this works.

Comment: I don't know what "modern" means. There's nothing wrong with doing that, and that's how I would expect to do it myself. Very few things in C++ can be accomplished by calling some function with a pretty name, from some class or library. Most of the time one has to do the dirty work all by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I'm trying to make this as-platform-independent as I can. Therefore I need to deal with endianness. For only one number it's straithtforward, but if the input is huge there shall be a loop as well, and I think modern C++ (11 and above) has some really cool features for these common scenarios - I just don't know them.

Comment: The "cool features" in question just provide a convenient shortcut for iterating over a container in a safe way.